# Grails layout doesn't change

Tags: css, layout, grails, staticresource

I have exported grails application from STS on one PC and imported it with STS on another. But know my layout doesnt render properly. It kept some previous settings like images and css. How can I repair this?

Comment: You have not given enough information on what "does not render properly" means. Please give further information - does it show errors, are you missing resources, are there errors in the log?

Comment: @JanWikholm Actually I did. But maybe I wasn't clear enough. I said it kept some images and CSS settings. I've changed a bit default main.css file, and also the grails logo image to something else. But when I run the app it renders the old css settings and Grails logo. I hope this clears it.

Comment: @JanWikholm I've just deployed the app on Tomcat server and the views are rendered properly - images and css also. So what's the problem with the local machine and run-app?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could respond and tell whether my answer worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

The web-app/WEB-INF/ might contain cached versions of your static resources, I would recommend running `grails clean` and then trying to run-app again.

also `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ["/images/*", "*.css"]` in `Config.groovy` might help

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I tried `grails clean` before but it didn't work. I've tried your advice for `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns` and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your Config.groovy in conf folder (probably only for development)

```
 grails.resources.debug = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's problem with reloading gsp files? Try this:

```
grails.gsp.enable.reload=true
```